# Canceling a custom drag function when mouse slides off div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a draggable function in jquery to make it so I can drag and move elements on a div. Sometimes, when dragging the mouse comes off the div and I am not able to put back down the element.

I'm trying to add a `keydown` event for the escape button or something so that when pressed, the same thing happens on `.on("mouseup", function(event) {`

I've tried doing `.on("mouseup keydown", function(event) {` but it doesn't catch any keys that are being pressed.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can cancel the drag? Either by a `keydown` or even on a `mouseup` regardless of if the mouse is on the div or not that is being dragged?

Just to be clear, the problem I am having is sometimes I will be dragging the element, I will `mouseup` but the mouse wasn't on the element when `mouseup` was called. Therefore, the element is still dragging and I no longer have my finger on the mouse and I have no way to stop the element from dragging to get it back on the document.

## **EDIT**: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spk4523t/1/), notice I am trying to get this to work on a scaled container. [youtube video showing drag glitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVMGx13icHQ)

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.drags = function(opt, callback) {
        opt = $.extend({
            handle: "",
            cursor: "move"
        }, opt);
        if (opt.handle === "") {
            var $el = this;
        } else {
            var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
        }
        return $el.css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function(e) {
            if (opt.handle === "") {
                var $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
            } else {
                var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
            }
            var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'),
                drg_h = $drag.outerHeight(),
                drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(),
                pos_y = $drag.offset().top + drg_h - e.pageY,
                pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;
            $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function(e) {
                $('.draggable').offset({
                    top: e.pageY + pos_y - drg_h,
                    left: e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w
                }).on("mouseup", function() {
                    $(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
                });
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }).on("mouseup", function(event) {
            if (opt.handle === "") {
                $(this).removeClass('draggable');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
            }

            if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                alert("this is a callback");
            }

        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Did you try adding the `keydown` event listener to the `window`? Unless the element being dragged has `focus`, it will not receive key events.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I have a callback in my function, so adding a `keydown` to `window` would cause the callback to occur at times it's not ready for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few things that might work:

Instead of listening for `mouseup` on the target element, listen for it on `document.body`. That way it will fire regardless of if the cursor is over the dragged element.

If you want to cancel the drag when the cursor wanders out of the page, add an event listener for `mouseleave` on document.body and use it to cancel the drag.

If you make a code-pen (or similar) test case, I will be happy to dig into the code.

Edit__

Handling `mouseleave` on the document prevents it from getting stuck in a draggable state. It also fixes the multiplied movement that you were seeing.

```
$(document.body).on('mouseleave', function(){
    $el.removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);
});
```

Edit2__

Previous JSFiddle was incorrect.

https://jsfiddle.net/spk4523t/6/

Comment: I posted a jsfiddle in my question. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: This works great, however, I added `$(document.body).on('mouseleave mouseup` and the problem is, I only want this to happen when I am dragging an element (mouseup especially). The way it works now is whenever my mouse leaves the content area or I mouseup my callback occurs when I don't want it to.

Comment: You have to make a compromise. There is no way to detect mouse events outside of the window. If you mouseup outside of the window, there is no way to tell. The best way is to cancel the drag if they leave the window.

Comment: I'm not trying to detect it outside of the window. I am trying to detect the mouseup event if the drag event is still occurring but the glitch happens and my mouse is no longer on top of said dragged element. I added a youtube video to explain the glitch in more detail in my original question.

Comment: you can add a boolean check to see if the element is currently being dragged. If it is, fire the callback. If it's not, then don't. JSFiddle won't let me sign up for an account right now, so I can't save my changes...

Comment: Hmm I guess that could work. I don't have a jsfiddle account? Just click update

Comment: Ah, that's how it works. Check the fiddle now. I implemented my suggestions. You can do something similar with a keydown event to cancel the drag.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71293/discussion-between-posit-labs-and-bryan).